# Swift error: Execution was interrupted reason: EXC_BREAKPOINT

Tags: swift

I renamed a file. No errors appeared in my code but yet received this message. Help please! [Error given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ce9Oy.png) (not sure why stack asks me for more info, but I have tried all things to resolve the issue eg, DerivedData, making a new playgrounds, ect) (I can't input my whole code here unfortunately, would really appreciate the help because I'm still relatively new to Swift and I don't even know what's EXC_BREAKPROINT(code=1) error is about despite googling for solutions.)

Affected Code:

Let intro = IntroViewController()

```
    import Foundation 
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

public class IntroViewController: UIViewController {
    func onMain(_ block: @escaping () -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: block)
    } 

    var previousBtn: UIButton!
    var nextBtn: UIButton!
    var pageLabel: UILabel!
    var pages = [UIView]()
    var pageNum = 0
    let slide = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 350, width: 350, height: 250))
    let slide2 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 310, width: 350, height: 250))

    var secondView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 410, height: 600))

        let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 50, width: 300, height: 100))
        headerLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .bold)
        headerLabel.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        headerLabel.text = "So...what is Mental health about? "
        headerLabel.numberOfLines = 2

        let descriptionLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 150, width: 300, height: 120))
        descriptionLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .medium)
        descriptionLabel.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        descriptionLabel.text = """
            Mental health consists of...
             - Physical well-being ️
             - Emotional well-being 
             - Psychological well-being 
            And many more!
            """
        descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 7

        let description2Label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 250, width: 350, height: 130))
        description2Label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .medium)
        description2Label.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        description2Label.text = "It affects how we think, act, handle stress and make choices."
        description2Label.numberOfLines = 0

        let img = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 400, width: 300, height: 150))
        img.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "graph1.jpg")

        view.addSubview(headerLabel)
        view.addSubview(descriptionLabel)
        view.addSubview(description2Label)
        view.addSubview(img)

        let subviews = view.subviews
        for view in subviews {
            view.isHidden = true
        }

        return view
    }()

    var thirdView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 410, height: 600))

        let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 10, width: 300, height: 100))
        headerLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .bold)
        headerLabel.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        headerLabel.text = "How does it affects people? "
        headerLabel.numberOfLines = 2

        let directedGraph = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 100, width: 350, height: 50))
        directedGraph.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
        directedGraph.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        directedGraph.text = "Mental Health affects people from all ages. From young  till old ‍"
        directedGraph.numberOfLines = 5 

        let directedDescription = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 150, width: 350, height: 50))
        directedDescription.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .medium)
        directedDescription.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        directedDescription.text = "Positive and Negative mindset could affect mental health in many ways!"
        directedDescription.numberOfLines = 10
        
        let img11 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 200, width: 350, height: 150))
        img11.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "img1.1.png")
         

        let weightedGraph = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 350, width: 350, height: 50))
        weightedGraph.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
        weightedGraph.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        weightedGraph.text = "Stats: Suicide rates in Asia (Teenage)"
        weightedGraph.numberOfLines = 2

        let weightedDescription = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 400, width: 350, height: 50))
        weightedDescription.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .medium)
        weightedDescription.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        weightedDescription.text = "the attached picture shown below is a chart that shows teen deaths caused by suicide in 2016."
        // credits WHO
        weightedDescription.numberOfLines = 6

        let img2 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 80, y: 450, width: 300, height: 200))
        img2.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pic2.png")

        view.addSubview(headerLabel)
        view.addSubview(directedGraph)
        view.addSubview(directedDescription)
        view.addSubview(weightedGraph)
        view.addSubview(weightedDescription)
        view.addSubview(img2)
        view.addSubview(img11)

        let subviews = view.subviews
        for view in subviews {
            view.isHidden = true
        }

        return view
    }()


    var fourthView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 410, height: 600))

        let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 20, width: 300, height: 100))
        headerLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .bold)
        headerLabel.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        headerLabel.text = "How can you  your mental health?"
        headerLabel.numberOfLines = 2

        let descriptionLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 100, width: 300, height: 150))
        descriptionLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .medium)
        descriptionLabel.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        descriptionLabel.text = "There are many ways to improve your mental health! Such as exercising , playing your favorite sport ️. But most importantly, eating well and getting adequate sleep is very important as having enough sleep can lower the risk of mental health problems"
        descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        let img = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 250, width: 400, height: 250))
        img.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "manybrainslawls.png")

        let explain = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 500, width: 300, height: 100))
        explain.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .medium)
        explain.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackAmount
        explain.textAlignment = .center
        explain.text = "Continuing on "
        explain.numberOfLines = 0

        view.addSubview(headerLabel)
        view.addSubview(descriptionLabel)
        view.addSubview(img)
        view.addSubview(explain)

        let subviews = view.subviews
        for view in subviews {
            view.isHidden = true
        }

        return view
    }()


    var fifthView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 410, height: 600))

        let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 20, width: 300, height: 100))
        headerLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .bold)
        headerLabel.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        headerLabel.text = "Part 2 !"
        headerLabel.numberOfLines = 1

        let explain = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 100, width: 300, height: 100))
        explain.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .medium)
        explain.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        explain.text = "Besides from doing your favorite activities...here's what you can do to relieve stress & anxiety !"
        explain.numberOfLines = 0

        let home = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 210, width: 300, height: 50))
        home.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
        home.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        home.text = "Be positive! Nothing is impossible! "
        home.numberOfLines = 2

        let access = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 270, width: 300, height: 50))
        access.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
        access.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        access.text = "Get a diary! "
        access.numberOfLines = 1

        let friends = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 310, width: 300, height: 50))
        friends.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
        friends.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        friends.text = "MediTatE! "
        friends.numberOfLines = 1

        let plant = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 350, width: 300, height: 50))
        plant.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
        plant.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        plant.text = "Talk to a friend! "
        plant.numberOfLines = 1

        let approaches = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 400, width: 300, height: 100))
        approaches.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .medium)
        approaches.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackAmount
        approaches.text = "Continuing on..."
        approaches.numberOfLines = 0
        
        view.addSubview(headerLabel)
        view.addSubview(explain)
        view.addSubview(home)
        view.addSubview(access)
        view.addSubview(friends)
        view.addSubview(plant)
        view.addSubview(approaches)

        let subviews = view.subviews
        for view in subviews {
            view.isHidden = true
        }

        return view
    }()

    var sixthView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 410, height: 600))

        let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 20, width: 320, height: 100))
        headerLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36, weight: .bold)
        headerLabel.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        headerLabel.text = "undone"
        headerLabel.numberOfLines = 1

        let history = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 100, width: 320, height: 100))
        history.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .medium)
        history.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        history.text = "-"
        history.numberOfLines = 0

        let explain = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 220, width: 320, height: 100))
        explain.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .medium)
        explain.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        explain.text = "-"
        explain.numberOfLines = 0

        let img3 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 350, width: 350, height: 250))
        img3.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "img3.jpeg")

        view.addSubview(headerLabel)
        view.addSubview(history)
        view.addSubview(explain)
        view.addSubview(img3)

        let subviews = view.subviews
        for view in subviews {
            view.isHidden = true
        }

        return view
    }()

    var seventhView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 410, height: 600))

        let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 20, width: 350, height: 100))
        headerLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .bold)
        headerLabel.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        headerLabel.text = "Stress management tips! "
        headerLabel.numberOfLines = 1

        let history = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 100, width: 310, height: 180))
        history.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .medium)
        history.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        history.text =
            """
            here are 5 tips that could help you relieve stress in tough situations (eg. Examinations, Presentations, ect)
            1. Before the examintion/presentation, take a deeeeep breath! (inhale & exhale )
            2.
            4.
            5.
            """
        history.numberOfLines = 0

        let slide = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 310, width: 350, height: 250))
        slide.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "graph6_0.png")

        view.addSubview(headerLabel)
        view.addSubview(history)
        view.addSubview(slide)

        let subviews = view.subviews
        for view in subviews {
            view.isHidden = true
        }

        return view
    }()

    var eigthView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 410, height: 600))

        let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 20, width: 350, height: 100))
        headerLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36, weight: .bold)
        headerLabel.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        headerLabel.text = "Conclusion "
        headerLabel.numberOfLines = 1

        let explore = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 100, width: 350, height: 150))
        explore.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
        explore.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        explore.text = "It is totally normal for us humans to feel upset, angry and dissapointed at ourselves"
        explore.numberOfLines = 3

        let run = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 200, width: 350, height: 150))
        run.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
        run.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        run.text = "No matter what, do your best and have a lil faith in ourselves! Thanks for reading! "
        run.numberOfLines = 3

        view.addSubview(headerLabel)
        view.addSubview(explore)
        view.addSubview(run)

        let subviews = view.subviews
        for view in subviews {
            view.isHidden = true
        }

        return view
    }()

    var firstView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 410, height: 600))

        let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 50, width: 300, height: 100))
        headerLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .bold)
        headerLabel.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        headerLabel.text = "What is Mental Health about? "
        headerLabel.numberOfLines = 2

        let basicLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 250, width: 350, height: 40))
        basicLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
        basicLabel.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        basicLabel.text = "How does it affect people ?"
        basicLabel.numberOfLines = 2

        let mw2Label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 300, width: 350, height: 40))
        mw2Label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
        mw2Label.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        mw2Label.text = "How can you  your mental health?"
        mw2Label.numberOfLines = 2

        let mw3Label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 350, width: 350, height: 40))
        mw3Label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
        mw3Label.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        mw3Label.text = "Stress management tips! "
        mw3Label.numberOfLines = 2

        let endLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 400, width: 300, height: 40))
        endLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25, weight: .semibold)
        endLabel.textColor = Colors.Fonts.blackDefault
        endLabel.text = "Conclusion "
        

        view.addSubview(headerLabel)
        view.addSubview(basicLabel)
        view.addSubview(mw2Label)
        view.addSubview(mw3Label)
        view.addSubview(endLabel)

        return view
    }()

    func slideShow2() {
        var num = 0
        while runSlideShow2, isAnimating {
            onMain {
                self.slide2.removeFromSuperview()
                self.pages[6].addSubview(self.slide2)
            }
            num = (num + 1) % 4
            usleep(250 * 1_000)
            if !(runSlideShow2 && isAnimating) {
                break
            }
            usleep(250 * 1_000)
            if !(runSlideShow2 && isAnimating) {
                break
            }
            usleep(250 * 1_000)
            if !(runSlideShow2 && isAnimating) {
                break
            }
            usleep(250 * 1_000)
        }
        self.slide2.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    func slideShow() {
        var num = 0
        while runSlideShow, isAnimating {
            onMain {
                self.slide.removeFromSuperview()
                self.pages[5].addSubview(self.slide)
            }
            num = (num + 1) % 6
            usleep(250 * 1_000)
            if !(runSlideShow && isAnimating) {
                break
            }
            usleep(250 * 1_000)
            if !(runSlideShow && isAnimating) {
                break
            }
            usleep(250 * 1_000)
            if !(runSlideShow && isAnimating) {
                break
            }
            usleep(250 * 1_000)
        }
        self.slide.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    let myqueue = DispatchQueue(label: "myQQ", attributes: [])

    var isAnimating = false
    var runSlideShow = false
    var runSlideShow2 = false

    @objc func nextTapped() {
        pageNum += 1
        if isAnimating {
            isAnimating = false
        }
        onMain {
            if self.pageNum == 7 {
                self.nextBtn.isHidden = true
            }
            if self.pageNum == 1 {
                self.previousBtn.isHidden = false
            }
            if self.pageNum == 5 {
                self.runSlideShow = true
            } else {
                self.runSlideShow = false
            }
            if self.pageNum == 6 {
                self.runSlideShow2 = true
            } else {
                self.runSlideShow2 = false
            }
            self.pageLabel.text = "Page \(self.pageNum + 1)"
            self.pages[self.pageNum - 1].removeFromSuperview()
            self.view.addSubview(self.pages[self.pageNum])
        }
        let prevSubs = pages[pageNum - 1].subviews
        for view in prevSubs {
            view.isHidden = true
        }
        let subviews = pages[pageNum].subviews
        myqueue.async {
            self.isAnimating = true
            for view in subviews where self.isAnimating {
                self.onMain {
                    UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                        view.isHidden = false
                    })
                }
                if !self.isAnimating {
                    break
                }
                usleep(200 * 1_000)
            }
            if self.pageNum == 5 {
                self.slideShow()
            }
            if self.pageNum == 6 {
                self.slideShow2()
            }
            self.isAnimating = false
        }
    }

    @objc func previousTapped() {
        pageNum -= 1
        if isAnimating {
            isAnimating = false
        }
        onMain {
            if self.pageNum == 6 {
                self.nextBtn.isHidden = false
            }
            if self.pageNum == 0 {
                self.previousBtn.isHidden = true
            }
            if self.pageNum == 5 {
                self.runSlideShow = true
            } else {
                self.runSlideShow = false
            }
            if self.pageNum == 6 {
                self.runSlideShow2 = true
            } else {
                self.runSlideShow2 = false
            }
            self.pageLabel.text = "Page \(self.pageNum + 1)"
            self.pages[self.pageNum + 1].removeFromSuperview()
            self.view.addSubview(self.pages[self.pageNum])
        }
        let prevSubs = pages[pageNum + 1].subviews
        for view in prevSubs {
            view.isHidden = true
        }
        let subviews = pages[pageNum].subviews
        myqueue.async {
            self.isAnimating = true
            for view in subviews where self.isAnimating {
                self.onMain {
                    UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                        view.isHidden = false
                    })
                }
                if !self.isAnimating {
                    break
                }
                usleep(200 * 1_000)
            }
            if self.pageNum == 5 {
                self.slideShow()
            }
            if self.pageNum == 6 {
                self.slideShow2()
            }
            self.isAnimating = false
        }
    }

    public override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.bounds.size.height = 770
        view.bounds.size.width = 450
        self.view = view
    }

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        previousBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 680, width: 100, height: 30))
        previousBtn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "arrow_left.png"), for: .normal)
        previousBtn.imageView?.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        previousBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(previousTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        previousBtn.isHidden = true

        nextBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 360, y: 680, width: 80, height: 30))
        nextBtn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "arrow_right.png"), for: .normal)
        nextBtn.imageView?.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        nextBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(nextTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        pageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 680, width: 100, height: 30))
        pageLabel.text = "Page \(pageNum + 1)"
        pages = [firstView, secondView, thirdView, fourthView, fifthView, sixthView, seventhView, eigthView]
        pageLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .medium)

        view.addSubview(pages[0])
        view.addSubview(pageLabel)
        view.addSubview(previousBtn)
        view.addSubview(nextBtn)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have renamed a file then make sure you clean the build folder and then build again. If that doesn’t work you can try to clean the DerivedData folder

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion! How can I do it? I'm relatively new to XCode. Do note that I received this error through XCode Playgrounds

Comment: Product/CleanBuildFolder, and for deleeting Derived data open Finder, take Goto (or similar) in the top menu and the press alt key, then the library folder is shown. There you can go to Developer/Xcode and you can delete Derived data.

Comment: I have cleared DerivedData... still doesn't work. Not sure why am I given the EXC_BREAKPOINT error when there's no issue with the code. I just simply renamed it and it still gives me the error.

Comment: I am not sure what file you rename in a playground, usually there are no files when working in a playground. I also think you should update your question and explain that this is in a playground and also give a more detailed explanation of what you did.

Answer (score -1):

There can be two approach to this:
rebuild all of your line
shortcut to cleaning is this one:
shift+command+K

as you said you renamed the file.other thing you can do is copy past all code  into new file with your requried name.
this should work if your code is good else please do share the code.

Comment: Ah I tried it. still didn't work. I have no errors in my code. I have deleted DerivedData, didn't work as well.

Comment: I have updated the question. Not sure whether it helps with the second picture attached.

Comment: its definitely up with code.have you tried using breakpoints in view controller that your initialising.have you make sure you have passed required parameters or information to you view controller so that any thing within isnt getting nil.
sharing the code will be helpfull .its just because of bad code likely.

Comment: share view controller?

Comment: am talking about using breakpoint for testing purposes

Comment: Ah I see, let me update my question with the code.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ep1EobCuIqwtrdqgFqzkI0yF7VYv4Rnc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: check if this helps

Comment: Ah thanks! Let me put my playgrounds here... And if possible could you tell me how I could solve the error? Thanks really much!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lrii0oIdX6XA7uXW5egKMjs9S0ipsRFM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14laA8wrVRXXq6FEuDGgwJfkKmX9nAfDQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: its just the way you write code.dont use image literal i found many literal resource name to be invalid.
hope it works
give it a vote.

Comment: Ah thank you really much! I found out why I was given the error already. Thanks really much!!